# If x is at the 70th percentile, can we say what percentile we expect y to be compared to other values with x at the 70th percentile?

Tags: statistics

A scatter diagram of MSAT and VSAT scores of a large group of students is football shaped (homoscedastic). The correlation is positive but not 1.

If a student is at the nth percentile (say, 70th) on the VSAT and on the mth percentile (say, 60th) on the MSAT, can we say whether the student's MSAT score is greater than/equal to/less than the average MSAT score of all students on the 70th percentile of the VSAT score?

Presuming the regression line approximates it well, we have $z_Y = r z_X$ where $r$ is the correlation coefficient.
If a student scored on the 70th percentile on the VSAT, it corresponds to a standard deviation around $z_X = 0.525$, so $0 < z_Y < 0.525$ which corresponds to a lower percentile. Seeing as he scored at the 70th percentile, can we conclude he scored better than average compared to the others who scored 70th percentile on the VSAT?

Comment: In such a dataset, in reality, knowing the percentile of a data point on the x axis (VSAT) tells you nothing for sure about where it lies on the y axis (MSAT), even if there is a positive correlation or beta in a linear regression. You know something about the behavior of the group, but not about any particular individual point.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too. I believe I would need to find (y-y_{avg at 70th percentile})/(SD_y * (1-r^2)^1/2)), right? But since I don't know the average at the 70th percentile, we can't know anything for certain?

Comment: In reality (I deal with data like this) data are noisy, there are outliers etc. Consider a student who prepares well for the VSAT but then bombs the MSAT because they're hungover or whatever. Or, they're simply good at VSAT and not MSAT material, despite most people getting similar scores on both tests (hence the group correlation). You can talk about shapes, characteristics, relations of the group (or subgroups), but you can't predict the actual values for an individual in this kind of situation.